# Laravel configuration usage for different servers in pure php file

Tags: laravel

I am new in Laravel and want to know such problem

I am running an web application on several server using Laravel.
But I have encountered with an issue.

When there is modification for the project, I need to sync with git on several servers.
But it has different settings for each server (eg: DB name, DB password...)
I have set it manually because I couldn't use .env or configuration file since the file is just pure php file.
The issue I want to solve is how can I get Laravel configuration data from pure PHP file(not controller or whatever).
It will be thankful if someone teach me solution.

Comment: Please add more information and share code samples

Comment: FYI, you could define separate .env files for all your servers. For example, .env.a, .env.b, .env.c etc. For each of your servers you can use this env files without changing your configuration files. Each .env file could defne a DB_NAME for your server. You can use then like config('db.name').

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> how can I get Laravel configuration data from pure PHP file

The answer would be this:

You just make some file in config/ folder of laravel app (or use the existing file like config/app.php)

You make an array of your key value pairs

```
<?php

return [

    'some_key' => 'some_value',

...
```

and you simply call it with this code where ever you need it:

```
config('config_file.key');
```

for example

```
config('app.name');
```

would give you `Laravel` by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @lewis4u
But I just created a test.php file
and tried to display:
`echo config('app.name');`

anyhow it doesn't work.
I think we can use that config() function only in controller or some class that extends controller.
Just my thought.
Please let me know your opinion.
Thans

Comment: Where did you run that echo ??? I mean that `config('file.key')` works everywhere in blade in custom helper classes, anywhere! config() is laravels helper function and it get's loaded when you access your web app